# Gradle does not Sync Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I keep getting this error when I try to sync my gradle project

```
Error:org.gradle.tooling.LongRunningOperation.addProgressListener(Lorg/gradle/tooling/events/ProgressListener;)Lorg/gradle/tooling/LongRunningOperation;
```

I've tried updating Gradle, Android studio and the likes but nothing is working.

Comment: add your build.gradle

Comment: @mehrdadkhosravi added

Comment: my mean was build.gradle(app)

Comment: Delete your gradle folder and re-download gradle